# UIImageView tap to hide navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have a view which shows an image from the web. The view only has an `UIImageView`. I want to know how to hide the `navigationBar` when the user taps and show it again when the user re-taps the view again. (Just like the native iPhone photo app)

I know i can use this

> [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

but i am not sure where to use this,where to put in this code.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a new `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleNavigationBar:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[tapGestureRecognizer release];
```

You also must make sure the UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled set to **`YES`** because by default it is set to `NO` on `UIImageView`'s.

```
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Finally, write the method that is called when the gesture recognizer recognizes. This is the method selector that is passed in the `action:` argument in the gesture recognizer's initializer method:

```
- (void)toggleNavigationBar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thats exactly wat i am doing. But the toggleNavigatorBar method is not called :(. Am i missing something very obvious?

Comment: Is `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` on the UIImageView?  Also make sure that `exclusiveTouch` is set to `NO` on all he views and subviews you are dealing with so you can be sure that none of those are blocking the touch event.

Answer (score 2):

Put a UITapGestureRecognizer on your UIImageView and in the delegate just call the method you mentioned. Something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* g = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
[img addGestureRecognizer:g];
[g release];
```

Then your delegate:

```
-(void) imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tg
{
    if(self.navigationController.toolbarHidden)
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    else
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i find the delegate method never being called.

Comment: try setting user interaction enabled on image view. Like `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out the other answers you can cheat a little bit. You can throw on a button set it to transparent and link a IBAction to it with the code:

```
UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( x,y,0,0)];
imageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navBarHide:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)navBarHide {
if (!navBarHidden) {

[self.navigationController.navigationBar removeFromSuperView];

}
else {

[YourUIView addSubview: yourNavigationBar];

}
}
```